# I've started my Docker container but it is not staying up

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, containers, devops

After creating container, I check with `sudo docker ps` and it shows like the following image.

[image: docker ps result]

Then I check with sudo `docker ps -a` and it shows it exited 36 seconds ago.

This is the code of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER srini <srinivasanacg@gmail.com>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN mkdir /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www_data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www_data
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV LANG C
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to first debug the container like this way.
**Dokckerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
MAINTAINER srini 
RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get install -y apache2 
RUN mkdir /var/lock/apache2 
ADD ./entry.sh /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www_data 
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www_data 
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid 
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2 
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2 
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2 
#ENV LANG C CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"] EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "entry.sh" ]
```

Now **entry.sh**

```
touch /var/lock/apache2/1.txt
tail -f /var/lock/apache2/1.txt
```

Start your container like this:

```
docker run -it --name $container_name -d $image_name
```

Now go inside your container like this :

```
docker exec -it $container_name bash
```

Manually start `apache2` like this :

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -D
```

And analyze the things where it is creating issue,check the logs and according to the analysis correct the `Dockerfile` steps.

Hope this help! 
Thank you!

Comment: It shows "Error response from daemon: Container e4f6f7353732526080d6507687d0707dd62e806c38d9265e8e49832cef80d82c is not running"

Comment: first `docker stop $container_name` than `docker rm -v $container_name` after that follow the steps provided by me.

Answer (score 0):

The APACHE_RUN_USER/APACHE_RUN_GROUP environment variables are incorrect. The user should be: **www-data**

```
➜  docker logs apache
AH00543: apache2: bad user name www_data
```